# Website Home Page URL Not Show On Google Search

Tags: google, google-search, search-engines, web-crawlers, googlebot

[image]

If i search like site:www.paka.tv my main homepage URL not showing, but categories of my site pages showing on results. How to show my website URL (www.pakka.tv) on google search.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:
1) insert tag
 base href="https://www.paka.tv/" in the head of all pages;
2) make 301 redirect from paka.tv to www.paka.tv ;
3) add site to google search console.
Now i can see 64 results for site:www.pakka.tv and about 7600 results for site:pakka.tv - it's not good.

Comment: can i get more details about your first point,  1) insert tag base href="https://www.paka.tv/" in the head of all pages;

Comment: Sorry, problems with formatting but i will try to fix it &lt;base href=https://www.paka.tv/&gt;

Comment: so, first point is not problem is i am right,

Comment: you should use site address or with "www" or without "www" but not both.

Comment: okay, and i have one more doubt, how can i submit N number url for the sitemap, now i have submitted the sitemap to google console, it takes only 500 url, but as you know my website consists lots of pages, how can i submit N number url to my sitemap.

Comment: Submit all pages URL in sitemap - Google will check it periodically and index pages with limited number each time. Whole index process may take a long period of time if number of pages is great.